# Is there a size limit for Erlang integers?

Tags: erlang, beam

I know that Erlang has arbitrary size integers, but is there a max limit on one of the standard implementations? If so, what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Erlang uses [bignum arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), and Integers in Erlang are limited by available memory on the machine.
Virtually, there is no limit on how large an Integer can be in Erlang.
Take a look on this document: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html
It has more detailed explanations regarding limits.

Comment: It seems like the limit is the VM memory, which is 536,870,911 bytes (537MB) on a 32bit system and 2,305,843,009,213,693,951 bytes (2.3EB) on a 64bit system. Since we can store data in the first 28 or 60 bits of a 32 or 64bit field, we should be able to store integers up to roughly 2^2^63.9 or 10^10^18.7, given 2.3EB of RAM on a 64bit machine, or 10^10^9, given half a gigabyte of ram on a 32bit machine.

Comment: I love that bignum is used, but thanks to tagging, small enough integers only take 1 word (no memory overhead).

Answer (score 0):

On 32-bit architectures: `-134217729 < i < 134217728` (28 bits).

On 64-bit architectures: `-576460752303423489 < i < 576460752303423488` (60 bits).

Comment: Those are the limits for small integers. I was asking about the big integers of arbitrary size.